# If else minifier

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have many lines of code like this.. this is just a 1 thing i am trying right now.

```
if (RI2.Text.Contains("SOS") || RI2.Text.Contains("WAR"))
{
     Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
}
if (RI2.Text.Contains("sos") || RI2.Text.Contains("war"))
{
     Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
}
```

How do i minify this code. i mean, its very ugly and there many lines of code similar to this.

is there any better way of doing this which i dont know.

please help. appreciate your time and help.

Comment: perhaps a switch statement is what you need?

Comment: You could put all the text to lowercase, and then check. You could also use a regex to search for all the valid text options.

Comment: yes a switch case statement is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do **one** call, like

```
//this will accept "SOS" and "sos"
if(RI2.Text.ToLower().Contains("sos") || 
      RI2.Text.ToLower().Contains("war")) 
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this regular expression.

- Ignores case in comparison (`SOS` and `sos` matched)
- Does not mutate the strings as you don't call `ToLower()`
- Only 2 lines of code

You can optionally [precompile](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance) the expression if the expression (`SOS|WAR`) is a constant for more performance.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(RI2.Text, "SOS|WAR", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
```

Comment: This is the better option. Converting the text to lower/upper case can have peculiar side-effects in some languages such as Turkish (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I fully understand your requirements, but here you go:

```
if(RI2.Text.ToLower().Contains("sos") || RI2.Text.ToLower().Contains("war")) {
  Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the string to lowercase removing one if statement and then use a linq any statement.

```
var search=new[] {"sos","war"};

if (search.Any(x=>RI2.Text.ToLower().Contains(x))) {
  Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat"); 
}
```

Or even make collection of matches to target urls.

```
var search = new Dictionary<string,string>{ 
   {"sos","http://mydomain.com/rabat"},
   {"war","http://mydomain.com/rabat"},
};
```

The use linq

```
var url=search.Keys.Where(x=>RI2.Text.ToLower().Contains(x)).Select(x=>search[x]).FirstOrDefault();
if (url!=null) {
  Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a extention to string as follows

```
public static bool Contains(this string value, string[] values)
    {
        foreach (string comparar in values)
        {
            if (value.ToUpper().Contains(comparar.ToUpper())) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if you make values a param then you can just use multiple values on the call line.  e.g. for `public static bool Contains(this string value, string[] values)` you can then do `myString.Contains("sos","war")`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the string to lower or upper case use [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) with ignore case

```
if (RI2.Text.IndexOf("sos",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0  || 
    RI2.Text.IndexOf("war",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 )
{
        Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(string.Equals("war", RI2.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                string.Equals("sos", RI2.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
```

Comment: He wants to test if it **contains** not **equals**. Contains does not take a StringComparison.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of string pairs, with one being the search string in upper case and the other being the redirect location.

Iterate through the list checking each search string against the upper-case text. If you find a match redirect to the location specified in the pair.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
var pattern = "(sos|war)";
if(Regex.IsMatch(RI2.Text.ToLower(), pattern))
    Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
```

Comment: Why use both a `ToLower()` and Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Given that both the Url for Response.Redirect are same

```
string lowerRI2 = RI2.Text.ToLower();
if (lowerRI2.Contains("sos") || lowerRI2.Contains("war"))
   Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/rabat");
```